# Security light sensor

Tags: wiring

I have a outdoor lighting  product with Brown(A) , Blue(N) , Red(Load) wiring but coming out of my old home  is red , black , green / yellow wires how to connect

Comment: just for curiousity, what country?

Comment: We can't possibly begin to guess what to do with the red wire, unless we know more about what this mystery product is, and what was there before  at that location.  (to be clear: there are NOT standard color codes, but color+context can tell you a lot).

Comment: What country is this in, and what make/model is the light?

Comment: /Users/howardmarzan/Desktop/thumbnail_IMG_0329.jpg/Users/howardmarzan/Desktop/thumbnail_IMG_0327.jpg it is a Australia product and a sensor light was there before

Comment: @Howard, do you actually believe that we have access to your computer's hard drive? .... please edit your post and add the pictures there